# 'Figure' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I used the following code to create a plot, it produced the error 'Figure' object is not callable.

The strange thing is, after I bumped into this error when I re-run earlier codes I used to plot other graphs that worked earlier, I started getting the same error too.

Libraries imported:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime
from scipy import stats
from geopy import distance
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
%matplotlib inline
```

Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20,10))
ax0 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax[0,0], x = df_delivery['Delivery Score'], y = df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax [0,1], x = df_delivery['Normalised Delivery'], y = df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
ax0.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Delivery Score')
ax1.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Normalised Delivery')
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-297-79a19867903b> in <module>
----> 1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20,10))
      2 ax0 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax[0,0], x = df_delivery['Delivery Score'], y = df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
      3 ax1 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax [0,1], x = df_delivery['Normalised Delivery'], y = df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
      4 ax0.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Delivery Score')
      5 ax1.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Normalised Delivery')

c:\Users\clari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, gridspec_kw, **fig_kw)
   1453 
   1454     """
-> 1455     fig = figure(**fig_kw)
   1456     axs = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey,
   1457                        squeeze=squeeze, subplot_kw=subplot_kw,

TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable
```

Earlier codes that worked (that didn't work when re-run, after I bumped into the error) & error message:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
sns.scatterplot(x = df_review['Review Score'], y = df_review['Sales Percentile'])
plt.show()
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-298-8370cbb7bf63> in <module>
      1 #Plot Sales Percentile vs Review Score
      2 
----> 3 plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
      4 sns.scatterplot(x = df_review['Review Score'], y = df_review['Sales Percentile'])
      5 plt.show()

TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please post code and tracebacks as text, not as images.

Comment: Hi, please see the added code and tracebacks above. Thanks!

Comment: tbh, if you use matplotlib a lot, seaborn is not recommended by me personally... it won't make things easier for you in many cases (customization is less felxible, and some bugs maybe...)

Comment: You have probably imported something that is stealing the figure namespace.  Restart your kernel and rerun the code with as few imports as possible (for that line its just `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; fig, axs = plt.subplots()`). Then start adding code again until you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import the function you need to use just before you use it.

for example, put 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' before the line that shows the error mesg, as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from datetime import datetime
from scipy import stats
from geopy import distance
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20,10))
import seaborn as sns
ax0 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax[0,0], x = df_delivery['Delivery Score'], y 
= df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(ax = ax [0,1], x = df_delivery['Normalised 
Delivery'], y = df_delivery['Sales Percentile'])
ax0.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Delivery Score')
ax1.set_title('Sales Percentile vs Normalised Delivery')
```

Hope this works.